# How does man-pages versions relate to Linux kernel and libc versions?

Tags: c, linux, manpage

I am working with Ubuntu 13.04 running a Linux kernel version 3.8.0-32-generic. The `man-pages` version is:

```
[manu@laptop] man-pages: man --version
man 2.6.3
```

I am wondering what is the link between this `man-pages` version and my kernel version. While programming in C, I am using a system call which man page (in section 2) has been added in `man-pages` 3.47. Is there any way for me to install in a clean way this man version. By clean I mean being sure that I don't update some man pages with thing that are not supported by my Linux kernel or my Linux libc.

Edit according to  Keith answer

```
[manu@laptop] man-pages: dpkg -l | grep "\-doc"
ii  libx11-doc                                  2:1.5.0-1ubuntu1.1                     all          X11 client-side library (development documentation)
ii  lmbench-doc                                 3.0-a9-1                               all          Documentation for the lmbench benchmark suite
ii  mozart-doc                                  1.4.0-8ubuntu1                         all          Mozart Programming System (Documentation)
ii  perl-doc                                    5.14.2-21                              all          Perl documentation
ii  texlive-doc-base                            2012.20120611-1                        all          TeX Live: TeX Live documentation
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended-doc               2012.20120611-5                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-recommended
ii  texlive-latex-base-doc                      2012.20120611-5                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-base
ii  texlive-latex-extra-doc                     2012.20120611-2                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-extra
ii  texlive-latex-recommended-doc               2012.20120611-5                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-recommended
ii  texlive-pictures-doc                        2012.20120611-5                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pictures
ii  texlive-pstricks-doc                        2012.20120611-2                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pstricks
ii  texlive-science-doc                         2012.20120611-2                        all          TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-science
ii  transcode-doc                               3:1.1.7-4                              all          Text console video-stream processing tool (documentation)
ii  ubuntu-docs                                 13.04.3                                all          Ubuntu Desktop Guide
ii  xorg-docs-core                              1:1.6-1ubuntu2                         all          Core documentation for the X.org X Window System
ii  xorg-sgml-doctools                          1:1.10-1                               all          Common tools for building X.Org SGML documentation
```

The result of searching for manpages packages

```
[manu@laptop] man-pages: dpkg -l | grep "manpages"
ii  manpages                                    3.44-0ubuntu1                          all          Manual pages about using a GNU/Linux system
ii  manpages-dev                                3.44-0ubuntu1                          all          Manual pages about using GNU/Linux for development
ii  manpages-posix                              2.16-1                                 all          Manual pages about using POSIX system
ii  manpages-posix-dev                          2.16-1                                 all          Manual pages about using a POSIX system for development
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.6.3` is the version of the `man` command, not of the installed man pages. It's not relevant to anything other than the `man` command itself. The man *pages* are managed separately from the `man` command, typically in a package whose name includes `-doc`.

Normally your package management system should keep the documentation in sync with your installed software. `dpkg -l` should tell you what version of each package you have.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about man version, so documentation packages only contain the textual information used by the man tool. I updated my question according to your answer, I am not able to find the package you mention but I have some manpages packages, but they don't include the information I need.

Comment: I guess  that man pages documentation is linked to the installed software, I have now to figure out how and why I have the 3.44 version of manpages and manpages-dev and not the 3.47 including the documentation I am looking for.